# Why doesn't lifetime elision work for a function that returns a Fn?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

According to [The Rust Book](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision), lifetime elision allows we to have this signature:

```
fn first_word(s: &str) -> &str {
...
}
```

Instead of this more verbose version:

```
fn first_word<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &'a str {
...
}
```

But [later in the same book](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch13-01-closures.html#moving-captured-values-out-of-closures-and-the-fn-traits), I found that I can't write this:

```
fn make_a_cloner(s: &str) -> impl Fn() -> String {
  move || s.to_string()
}
```

I have to give the return type a lifetime:

```
fn make_a_cloner(s: &str) -> impl Fn() -> String + '_ {
...
}
```

I'm a bit confused. Why don't we need to specify any lifetime when we return a `&str`, but we need to add `'_` when we return a `impl Fn() -> String`? Why doesn't the same elision rule apply in both cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As much as lifetime elision can be obscuring, Rust's syntax does want it to be clear when borrows occur. References are one such place that is a clear borrower and even for structs with lifetimes you are encouraged to use `MyStruct<'_>` for arguments and parameters so that the lifetime is obvious. There is a [`elided_lifetimes_in_paths`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#elided-lifetimes-in-paths) lint in the compiler to help with this, but is unfortunately allowed by default; I encourage you to add it in your own code.

However, when you return a `impl Trait` (with no lifetime) then there is no annotation to convey that a borrow has occurred. Adding the placeholder lifetime `+ '_` at least communicates to the compiler and other developers that a borrow is happening. As such, without a lifetime annotation returning a `impl Trait` will use `'static` by default unless there is some other part of the trait's type that conveys a borrow (i.e. `impl Trait<&'a T>` will be bound by `'a`, not `'static`).

This does not necessarily apply to `impl Trait` in other places (like function parameters).

Comment: So far my understanding is: lifetime elision only happens at signature (not function body) level, and if we look at `-> impl Fn() -> String` *only*, there is no way to tell if there is a borrow, so elision doesn't work the same way as when we can tell there is a borrow (returning `&str`). Is this correct?

Comment: @Kodra correct, that is what I am saying